# Find the equations of the tangents and normal to the curve $y^2+8x=0$ , parallel to $x+y+4=0$

Tags: calculus, geometry

I really need your help. I really can't understand the given course pack because it has lacking of information.

Comment: What is the slope of the tangent at a given point? Given the slope, and the point, can you find the equation of the tangent line?

Comment: You need to combine several concepts to solve this problem: Implicit differentiation, geometric interpretation of the derivative as the slope of a tangent line, the point-slope form of a line equation, the slope of a line perpendicular to another line.

Because of this, asking for general help on a question is very ambiguous as there's a very big range of concepts that you could have trouble with. This is why the community guidelines state that you should include your attempt in your question: It shows you put work in, and it helps the other users identify what exactly you have trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the **derivative** of a function will give you the **slope of the tangent line**. The curve that you are given has the formula of $y^{2}+8x=0$ (notice that this is a inverse form of the quadratic formula a.k.a tilted parabola). You will have to perform an **implicit differentiation** to get the derivative:
$$y^{2}+8x=0$$
$$2y\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)+8=0$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{4}{y}$$
Two lines will be **parallel** if their **slopes are equal**. Now you would need to find the slope of the line $x+y+4=0$. Since this is a linear equation, the slope is much easier to find, it is a constant, so you can just plug in some random values of x to find the corresponding y, and find the slope using the formula:
$$m=\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$$
Which, in this case, $m$ will be -1. Now, set the two slopes equal to each other and find y:
$$-\frac{4}{y}=-1$$
$$y = 4$$
Now, at the location y = 4, the tangent line of $y^{2}+8x=0$ will be parallel to the line $x+y+4=0$. At y = 4, x = -2 for the curve. Use the slope formula to derive the equation of the tangent line:
$$m = \frac{y-y_{0}}{x-x_{0}}$$
$$-1 = \frac{y-4}{x-(-2)}$$
That is the formula of the line tangent to the curve $y^{2}+8x=0$, and parallel to the line $x+y+4=0$. You can rearrange it if you want to.

As for the **perpendicular (or normal) line**, its slope will be **opposite reciprocal** to that of a tangent. It would be:
$$\frac{-1}{\frac{-4}{y}} = \frac{y}{4}$$
In a similar fashion, set this equals to the slope of the line to find the y-coordinate:
$$\frac{y}{4}=-1$$
$$y=-4$$
At $y=-4$, $x=-2$ (remember that this curve is a inverse parabola?). Plug these values into the slope formula and you are all set:
$$m = \frac{y-y_{0}}{x-x_{0}}$$
$$-1 = \frac{y-(-4)}{x-(-2)}$$

You can always double check this using a graphing tool. I hope this will help!!!